# my wordpress thumbnail does not display/ html output is not what I need

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom post and I am trying to display its elements. Title works fine.
Thumbnail does not.

PHP:

```
<?php
      $args = array( 'post_type' => 'course','post_status' => 'publish','posts_per_page' => 3,'order' => 'ASC');
      $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
     
      while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();?>
        <h1 class="home-header aligncenter"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
     
       <img src="<?php echo  wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( )); ?>" alt="">
     
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

In HTML while I see no image in the source code I get the following:

```
<img alt="" data-src="correct-file-url" class="lazyload" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==">
```

When I delete the src="dara:image.... in the browser the image renders correctly.

What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: the image is loading as base64 encoded thats why its not being rendered as normal image

Comment: and how can I prevent that?

Comment: Is this how you get the img `src` from wordpress  ?

Comment: yes. I used the php code mentioned above. the html is just what I found when inspecting the elements in the browser